# JavaScript: What's wrong with this constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I'm not entirely sure how to implement objects in JS.

Here is a constructor:

```
function FooList(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7)
{
    alert("constructing");
    this._arg1 = arg1;
    this._arg2 = arg2;

    this.refresh();
}
```

I am trying to call it here:

```
FOO_LIST = new FooList(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3,
    arg4,
    arg5,
    arg6,
    arg7
);
```

When I have all 7 args, it doesn't work. (No breakpoint in the constructor is hit; and the alert doesn't fire. Also, the method that contains the above code stops executing.)

However, this does result in the alert firing:

```
FOO_LIST = new FooList();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE** Perhaps this is a better way to define a constructor:

```
FooList = function() { }
```

rather than

```
function FooList() { }
```

However, even using the former approach, it still doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2:** Looks like Spinon and Russ Cam's comments were correct. One of the args was silently failing when I tried to evaluate it.

Comment: Are the variables `arg1-7` defined?

Comment: What are you passing as argument when you use the 7 args ?

Comment: @felix yes, they are, and @tarantula: jquery objects, strings, and a callback.

Comment: It works fine for me just like you have it in your question. I should add that I just called it with integer values for the args. There might be an exception happening with retrieving one of the args.

Comment: In your update, one is a function declaration, the other a function expression, which in some JavaScript engines in some circumstances can cause it's own problems - http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/

Comment: is `refresh` a property of `FooList` or defined on the prototype?

Comment: based on the fact that it works with neither a function declaration nor function expression, it sounds like it's a problem with the arguments you're passing to the function constructor. If you could post the code in context, I may be able to help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a trailing comma after the last `arg` which is going to cause problems for the JavaScript engines.

In addition, it would be better to use `var` in front of `FOO_LIST`, even if it is intentionally a global variable, as this a good habit to get into for all variable declarations and save you from potential problems with global variable overwriting in future.

For cases where you have functions with many parameters like like this, you might want to use the `arguments` object and index into it to get args 1-7.

Comment: sorry, that was my own typo entering it into the page.

Comment: Asking "why doesn't this code work" when you're not showing us the code that's running, isn't a great way to get the problem solved. More so when the example code works for the people who are trying to help ;)